# Why react hook usestate show an error message

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an useState, but when add user rendered, React show an error. I dont know why React show an error. it seems valid code

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
```

I have an error on delete function:

```
function App() {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

    const userAddHandler = input => {
        setUsers(prevState => {
            return [...prevState, input]
        })
    }

    const deleteUserHandler = userId => {
        setUsers(userData => {
            userData.filter(user => {
                return userId !== user.id
            })
        });
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <AddUser onAddUser={userAddHandler} />
            <UserLists users={users} onDelete={deleteUserHandler} />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

An error Message like this:

```
TypeError: userData is undefined
deleteUserHandler/<
src/App.js:17

  14 | 
  15 | const deleteUserHandler = userId => {
  16 |     setUsers(userData => {
> 17 |         userData.filter(user => {
  18 | ^            return userId !== user.id
  19 |         })
  20 |     });
```

when i return it, it show another error message:

```
Cannot update a component (`App`) while rendering a different component (`UserLists`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `UserLists`
```

My userLists is like this:

```
const UserLists = (props) => {
    return (
        <ul>
            {props.users.map((user) => {
                return (
                    <div
                        className={styles.userLists}
                        key={user.id}
                        onClick={props.onDelete(user.id)}
                    >
                        <Card>
                            <li>{`${user.username} (${user.age} Years Old)`}</li>
                        </Card>
                    </div>
                );
            })}
        </ul>
    );
};

export default UserLists;
```

Comment: What is the value of prevState in this file?

Comment: You do not return anything from your `setUser(userData => ...)` so it's like if you've done `setUsers()`

Comment: `onClick={props.onDelete(user.id)}` should be `onClick={() => props.onDelete(user.id)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning anything so it's `undefined`, need to `return` the data after `filter`.

```
const deleteUserHandler = userId => {
        setUsers(userData => {
            return userData.filter(user => {
                return userId !== user.id
            })
        });
```

Comment: i have another error `Cannot update a component (`App`) while rendering a different component (`UserLists`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `UserLists`, follow the stack trace as described in` i called on UserLists like this `<div
                        className={styles.userLists}
                        key={user.id}
                        onClick={props.onDelete(user.id)}
                    >
                        <Card>
                            <li>{`${user.username} (${user.age} Years Old)`}</li>
                        </Card>
                    </div>`

Comment: That's out of context here, I guess it's because you called  `onDelete` directly after render, try this `onClick={()=>{props.onDelete(user.id)}`.
If it doesn't work, then please do your investigation.

Answer (score 1):

```
const deleteUserHandler = userId => {
    const newData = userData.filter(user => userId !== user.id);
    setUsers(newData);
}
```

This is maybe the best way.

Comment: Thanks, its make our code clean and readable